# Heroku rails help to push app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My git console:

```
Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$ git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Home/.ssh/id_rsa':

 !  No such app as warm-spring-423

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
```

I have created a app named "vinderhimlen" that I want to push my rails app to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change your remote heroku (if you typed `git remote -v` youd still see warm-spring-423)  try something like this:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:vinderhimlen.git
```

Comment: git remote add heroku "git@heroku.com:vinderhimlen.git"

Comment: I have changed the migration file in my app on my local machine. But it don't seem to change anything when I use heroku rake db:migrate. I have run git push heroku master

Comment: so you can migrate on your local machine correct?  i would suggest viewing the trace when you try the migration.  if you cant figure it out through that try opening up a new question with all the info on that.